# How can I read an IP address from the user in a bash script?

Tags: bash

```
if [ "$1" == "-s" ]; then
  echo "Connecting to host.."
  scp root@IP_ADDRESS:/private/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db /private/var/mobile/Media/BackupSMS
  echo " "
  exit
fi
```

I need to ask user for a IP-address, that will then be placed where `IP_ADDRESS` is above. I'm new to scripts, but I'm trying.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the built in [`read` command](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html)

```
read IP_ADDRESS
```

or, if you want a nice prompt:

```
read -p "Enter ip address: " IP_ADDRESS
```

and then add a `$` to the scp line:

```
scp root@$IP_ADDRESS:/...
         ^
```

Comment: You can use `echo` to indicate to the user that you are waiting for input, ie. `echo "Enter an ip"` then use `read`

Comment: its not replacing the IP_ADDRESS with the one entered with the read -p. What's it supposed to look like?